# Get single integer from list on click

Tags: android, arraylist

This is my array-list/list.. i want single single value when i click on button and the value from list should be added in total..

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, -1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1]
```

things that i have tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < Score1.size(); i++) {

              score = Score1.get(i);
              score2 += score;
}
```

out put:

```
total﹕ 51
```

but this thing should happen only on button click..
i tried few things..but when i click button..total comes all together..but i don't want that.

Required output-

```
total=0
total=1
total=2
total=5
etc...
```

Comment: can you show how you want your desire out pot in list when button clicked..

Comment: Means you want only one item will add in score2 on one click of Button?

Comment: You want only single addition to be done on the button click?

Comment: when user click on button..one element from list should be added to total..at a time one element...on next button click next element should be added in total

Comment: .@ρяσѕρєя K yes..i want to do that

Comment: Do not use for loop with this.

Comment: @Mohit.. i have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare in Global

```
int  i = 0;
int score = 0;
```

In your Method

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    if(i<Score1.size()){
                                    score = Score1.get(i);
                                    i++;
                                    System.out.println(score); // or any task you want to do
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

In `score` your addition will be stored after every click.

Comment: your program will throws `arrayindexoutofboundsexception` when `i` value exceed  `Score1.size()` value..

Comment: @Mohit . Hey Thanks mohit. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's kind of simple what you want to do , you have to reinitialized with 0 after you make sum, I think is something like that :

```
int sum=0;


int Number=0;

for (int i = 0; i < Score1.size(); i++) {
Number++;
sum =0;
for(int j =0 ;j<Number;j++){
numberFromArray= Score1.get(j);
          sum = sum+numberFromArray;

}
System.out.println(sum);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
take a a vriable in your class
private int nextIndex = 0;
private int sum = 0;

on button click call this function
//onclick
   sum = getTotal(nextIndex);

private int getTotal(int index){
    if (index < myList.size()) {
        nextIndex++;
        return sum+myList.get(index);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to take random value from your list and add it to some 'total' variable by clicking on button.
Then you need write special method for getting such random value, e.g.:

```
private int getRandomValue() {
    int randIndex = random.nextInt(myList.size());
    int value = myList.get(randIndex);
    return value;
}
```

'random' - variable of 'Random' class.

Then use this method in OnClickListener. Hope it helps =)

**UPDATE**

I saw you edited your question and you want to get next value in list by clicking on button. Then, rewrite our method:

```
private int getNextValue(int index) {
    if (index < myList.size()) {
        return myList.get(index);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*index* - current index in your list that is changing by every click on button. Hope it helps =)